# Worksheet Selection Change Not Working

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code which on selection change of a cell searches a separate sheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Target.Value = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
Dim Finder, ClickRange
Set ClickRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A:A")
If Intersect(Target, ClickRange) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Set Finder = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A:A").Find(Target.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole)
If Finder Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
MsgBox (Finder.Row)
End Sub
```

However the code isn't working even though in ThisWorkbook I have the following code enabling events

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

My sheet names are as follows

[image: Worksheets]

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: FWIW - (a) Unless I am very confused, I don't think your `Workbook_Open` code is doing anything.  If events are disabled, the code won't run (and therefore events will stay disabled).  If events are enabled, it sets events to be enabled (which is pointless because they were already enabled). (b) Your `SelectionChange` code seems to work for me.

Comment: :/ I see what you mean but still no luck with it. Nothing happens on sheet3 when I switch. Even though the code is inside Sheet3 (Sheet3)

Comment: Place a `MsgBox` just inside the `SelectionChange` code and then see if the `MsgBox` is displayed.  If not, type `Application.EnableEvents = True` in the Immediate Window and press enter, then try again.

Comment: Thanks that worked

Comment: Sorry but it only works when I put it in the Immediate Window if it is not there then it doesn't work. :/.

Comment: Do you have a `Personal` workbook that could be changing the `EnableEvent` status when you start Excel, or any other Excel files open that are changing it?

Answer (score 2):

Open Immediate Window and type **?Application.EnableEvents**

What do you get? A True or False?

If you get True, all is well but if you get False that means Events are disabled somehow (not because of the selection change event code but maybe because of some other code in the workbook).

To enable it again, Type **Application.EnableEvents=True** in the Immediate Window.

Now place the following code on Sheet3 Module and see if that works fine for you.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
Dim sws As Worksheet
Dim Finder As Range
Set sws = Sheets("Sheet4")
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
    If Target <> "" Then
        Set Finder = sws.Range("A:A").Find(Target.Value, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not Finder Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox Finder.Row
        Else
            MsgBox Target.Value & " was not found on " & sws.Name & ".", vbExclamation, "Not Found!"
        End If
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try enabling and disabling events like below. This will not only ensure that `Events` are enabled but will avoid potential issue of calling the event in a loop.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    On Error Goto errExit
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Value = vbNullString Then Exit Sub

    Dim Finder As Range ', ClickRange
    'Set ClickRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A:A")

    '/* If this code is in Sheet3, you can use below */
    If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Set Finder = _
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A:A").Find(Target.Value, _
                                                        LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Finder Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    MsgBox (Finder.Row)

errExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Try this first and let us know what you get. Hope this helps.